# How to get browser back button event in angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am working on the browser back button event in my angular 12 application but if the application url is the last url in browser history than event is not getting trigger. I tried below solution but that are not working.

solution 1:

```
 router.events.forEach(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    if (event.url === 'popstate') {
      /* Do something here */

    }
  }
});
```

solution 2:

```
 location.subscribe(event => {
  console.log('do something');
  
});
```

solution 3: In solution 3, I am not able to get control in onPopState for any browser back button event

```
 @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
 onPopState(event) {
console.log('Back button pressed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe using rxjs in OnInit () of your component.

```
fromEvent(window, 'popstate').subscribe(()=>{
  // do what you want
  alert('here i am')
})
```

Also i have a hack to disable this button. Add this code in OnInit.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  history.pushState(null, '');

  fromEvent(window, 'popstate').subscribe(()=>{
  // show prompt or alert
  })
}
```